# Conditional Join act as a mater table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi sorry I could not find a way to best title what I am looking for.

Anyway I have an idea of how to do something but I just need a new pair of eyes to look at what I am trying to do to see if it is possible. I basically have two tables one which has a load of text and numbers and another one which acts like a master table so if anything is found in the second table use that otherwise only use what is found in the first table. However I am unsure how to complete the select statement for this, I know i can go down the route of doing two separate select statements and union them up together but there must be an easier way. After playing around I have a query which I think may work but I am unsure if I have missed something. For example we have Table A and Table B (B holding the master data)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   A.ID, 
   COALESCE(B.PROD, A.PROD) AS PROD
   COALESCE(B.TEXT1, A.TEXT1) AS TEXT1, 
   COALESCE(B.NUMBER, A.NUMBER) AS NUMBER
FROM
   TABLEA A
   FULL OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.PROD = B.PROD
```

Now what I want is the statement to pick up the following information

- Anything found in Table A but not in Table B
- Anything found in Table B not in Table A
- Anything in Table B as the master which is found in
  in Table A

I added a full outer join as there maybe items in table B not in Table A

Will the query work, i have checked against out data and it seems to work however I am not sure if i have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a distinct in the select statement

Comment: What was wrong with the statement you had? From your description of what you want it seems like it would work (apart from the missing `DISTINCT`). Can you include sample data and expected results? Rather than comment hough, please update your question so people know you have `DISTINCT` in your query.

Comment: i think you want cross join with distinct record

Comment: It looks fine. I am not sure about the data you have in the tables. But you are taking A.ID directly even though TableA is your fallback table. You may should pick B.ID first if there is. Again, we do not know what data you have in the tables

Comment: Hi I tried to Edit it to include the distinct but could not, so I commented that I forgot to include it.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Hi I tried to edit to include distinct but could not, hence my comment. Basically this was just a sample statement actually I have one table full of sales, second table which describes of the product sold what material is it made up of and how much used. However due to the way we have got the data we may find that the amounts are incorrect or missing so I am creating a master table which will hold all the correct/amended data which will be added by users directly via an app. Naturally i need a way to be able to use these amounts if it is in the secondary table (table B).